# Error in inserting data to datatable angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Guys I'm new in angular and I want to insert my nodeJs server data to Datatable, So I followed all steps of datatable component but the data source didn't know the property of template.

> > ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fname' of undefined
> >         at DashboardComponent_mat_cell_58_Template (dashboard.component.html:72)
>
> ```
> at executeTemplate (core.js:11930)
>
>
> at refreshView (core.js:11777)
>
>
> at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
>
>
> at refreshView (core.js:11800)
>
>
> at refreshComponent (core.js:13217)
>
>
> at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11508)
>
>
> at refreshView (core.js:11829)
>
>
> at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13142)
>
>
> at refreshView (core.js:11800)
> ```

my html:

```
<mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource">
                <ng-container matColumnDef = "Agent">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Agent </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.Fname}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef = "cin">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CIN </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.CIN}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                    <ng-container matColumnDef = "email">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> E_mail </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.email}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef = "age">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.age}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef = "role">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Role </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.Role}} </mat-cell>

                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dispalyedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dispalyedColumns"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>
        </div>
```

main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { CollectionService } from '../collection.service';
import { Collection_info } from '../modules/Collection_info';
import { User_info } from '../modules/User_info';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections'
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  Collection_info: Collection_info[];
  User_info: User_info[];
  dataSource = new User_infoDataSource(this.CollectionService);
 dispalyedColumns = ['Agent','cin','email','age','role'];
  constructor(private CollectionService: CollectionService, private router: Router) { }//, private User_info: User_info

  ngOnInit() {
    }
export class User_infoDataSource extends DataSource<any>{
  constructor(private CollectionService: CollectionService){
  super();}
  connect(): Observable<User_info[]>{
    return this.CollectionService.getUsers();
  }
  disconnect(){}
}
```

and my module

```
export interface User_info{
    Fname: String;
    CIN: String;
    email: String;
    age: String;
    Role: String;
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize the array. `User_info: User_info[] = [];` Also, in the html you should use `User_info?.property_name`, so if the data is missing it wont throw an error.

Comment: `User_info: User_info[] = [];` solved my problem but the table is empty now

Comment: Your `User_info` is an array of `User_info`. ps: you realy need to clean your code man, it is a mess.

Comment: The list is empty because you are not `subscribing` to the method `connect`. You wont see the request in the network tab either. Maybe this will help you out: new `User_infoDataSource(this.CollectionService).connect().subscribe(result => this.dataSource = result;)});`

Comment: `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info.Fname}} </mat-cell>` should be 
`<mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.Fname}} </mat-cell>`

Comment: Yeah thanks Guys `{{user.Fname}}` solced my problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jacopo Mentioned in the comments : 
make sure you initialize the `User_info` variable as empty array.

`User_info: User_info[] = [];`

Also in the HTML template , it is a good practice to have `User_info?.property_name` while accessing the dynamic data . So your Template should look like below :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef = "Agent">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Agent </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{User_info?.Fname}} </mat-cell>

 </ng-container>
```

> Why my code is not working ?

Since JS is Asynchronous, It doesn't wait for any IO request to get completed. Instead it will keep executing next line of codes.

Since you are getting the value from service , the view is getting initialized before the service returns the data. And at that time the value of `User_info` is `undefined` because you have not initialized it.